# How to remove Cell content in xlsx file using apache POI

Tags: java, apache-poi

I want to remove cell content in xlsx file.
My code:

```
    static void RemoveCell(XSSFSheet mySheet) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException {
    int rownum = mySheet.getLastRowNum();
    for (int i = 0; i < rownum; i++) {
        Row currentRow = mySheet.getRow(i);
        Cell cell = currentRow.getCell(0);
        if (cell.getCellType() != Cell.CELL_TYPE_BLANK) {
            cell.setCellType(Cell.CELL_TYPE_BLANK);
        }
    }
}
```

But it not work.
Thank!

Answer (score 2):

If the requirement is removing only the cell contents but remaining the formats and comments, as described in [Clear cells of contents or formats](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Clear-cells-of-contents-or-formats-9ff6b8ff-1afd-495f-8ad8-8c1f6f82a9d6), then the following should work:

```
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.*;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.*;

import java.io.*;

class ExcelRemoveCellContent {

 static void removeCellContentsColumnA(XSSFSheet sheet) throws Exception {
  int rownum = sheet.getLastRowNum();
  for (int i = 0; i < rownum+1; i++) {
   XSSFRow row = sheet.getRow(i);
   if (row != null) {
    XSSFCell cell = row.getCell(0);
    if (cell != null) {
     if (cell.getCTCell().isSetT()) cell.getCTCell().unsetT();
     if (cell.getCTCell().isSetV()) cell.getCTCell().unsetV();
    }
   }
  }
 }

 public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{

  InputStream inp = new FileInputStream("ExcelRemoveCellContent.xlsx");
  Workbook workbook = WorkbookFactory.create(inp);

  Sheet sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);

  removeCellContentsColumnA((XSSFSheet)sheet);

  workbook.write(new FileOutputStream("ExcelRemoveCellContent.xlsx"));
  workbook.close();

 }
}
```

The `cell.getCTCell()` returns a [CTCell](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.apache.poi/ooxml-schemas/1.1/org/openxmlformats/schemas/spreadsheetml/x2006/main/CTCell.java). See the link for it's methods.

To clear all contents, formats, and comments that are contained in the selected cells (**Clear All**), simply use [Row.removeCell](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/Row.html#removeCell(org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Cell)).